# $G_{\mu\nu}$'s field equations in electromagnetic duality

Tags: electromagnetism, duality

Given $$G^{\mu\nu} = -2 \frac{\partial L}{\partial F_{\mu\nu}}$$ it is written in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506035 that the field equations are (eq 1.8) $$\partial_{[\alpha} \star G_{\beta \gamma]}= 0$$

How is that? Why the dual and not the $G_{\mu\nu}$ itself? Here L is general form of Lagrangian which is a function of $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\partial_{[\alpha} \star G_{\beta \gamma]}= 0$ is the anti-symmetrized way of writing the equation of motion. Please note that here we are considering duality.

Comment: Please incorporate the relevant content of the link into the post - in this case: What does $\partial_{[\alpha\star G_\beta\gamma]}$ mean? What kind of $L$ are we looking at?

Comment: I edited it, hope it is clearer now!

Comment: I don't know what "the antisymmetrization way of writing the e.o.m." is, and *which* duality are we considering? Is the $\star$ supposed to be the Hodge dual?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I have corrected his equation, using the arXiv reference. He just forgot to move the $G$ and $\star$ outside the subscript.

Comment: @JamalS: I see - am I correct that this is, written coordinate-free, just $\mathrm{d}\star G = 0$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Yes, the exterior derivative is an anti-symmetrized differentiation operator, so it's exactly that. In other words, the codifferential $\delta G = 0$. The OP's choice of notation is unfortunate since he combines tensor calculus and exterior calculus :)

Comment: oh, so what's the correct thing and how did he got to this? How did he derive it? @JamalS

Comment: @Fluctuations: For a generic Lagrangian describing a $G$ Lie algebra valued connection $A$, with curvature $F$, the equations of motion are $dF = d\star F = 0$. For example, for $G=U(1)$, since it is abelian, the additional curvature term (analogous to the $\nabla_{[u,v]}$ in the Riemann tensor) vanishes, and we have simply $F = dA$, from which it follows $dF = 0$, and the $d\star F = 0$ is equivalent to the Bianchi identity. Expressing the $F$ in terms of the electric and magnetic fields then gives you Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Yes, thank you for explaining this. But my question above was about the $G_{\mu\nu}'s$ equation of motion and not for F. Mind elaborating on this? 

Please note that $F_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow cos\alpha F_{\mu\nu} +sin\alpha * G_{\mu\nu}$ states the relation between F and G according to Hodge Duality @JamalS